# Dojo dialog appearing as static web page

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog

I am attempting to code a simple example of a Dojo dialog box.  I have copied the example shown in the Dojo reference here => http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Dialog.html

My code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Dialog Test</title>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                dojo.require("dojo.parser");
                dojo.require("dojox.widget.Dialog");
                dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
                dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer")
                dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane")
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dialogOne" dojoType="dojox.widget.Dialog" title="My Dialog Title">
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;">
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="foo">Content of Tab "foo"</div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="boo">Hi, I'm Tab "boo"</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>When pressing this button the dialog will popup:</p>
        <button id="buttonOne" dojoType="dijit.form.Button">Show me!
            <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
                // Show the Dialog:
                dijit.byId("dialogOne").show();
            </script>
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the page loads in a browser, the Dialog doesn't work.  I just see the text from the tabbed panes appear in the browser.

I've copied the code from the reference guide exactly so I'm very confused.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

James.

Comment: Did you include dojo, dijit & dojox in your page?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "include dojo, dijit & dojox in your page?"  I thought the use of dojo.require had the effect of including the source scripts?

Comment: You would need something like this in your page to load dojo.js from CDN (There are other ways to load dojo too) <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script> Probably this is a good starting point http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/hello_dojo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dojo samples unfortunately tend not to work fully 'as is', but are bits of skeleton code that need wrapping up in various standard bits of ceremony.

You've at least three things causing this not to work and render correctly. There may be other problems on top, but these will *definitely* cause it not to render:

1. You need to link to a version of the core Dojo scripts.  Linking to a CDN version is a simple way to go. e.g. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>`. Details are here: http://dojotoolkit.org/download/. Be sure to put this before your `require` scripting.
2. Add a link to a Dijit theme style sheet (CSS file) in your page, otherwise none of the widgets will display correctly.  e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css‌​"/>`
3. Add a `class` attribute on the body element describing which theme you want to use. e.g. `<body class="claro">`.

Only when you've done all those three things will it have a chance of working.  There may be other problems too, but they're the fundamental three.